# Linq query using generics

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Hi I have a following generic type method in my EF Repository

```
 public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        public EFRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            if (dbContext == null) 
                throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContext");
            DbContext = dbContext;
            DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
        }

        protected DbContext DbContext { get; set; }

        protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

        public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return DbSet;
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<T> GetById(int loc_id)
        {

            return DbSet(loc_id);
        }
     }
```

On DbSet(loc_id) i get intelisense saying "Method, delegate or event is expected"

Please let me know how to write this query properly to get list back using loc_id. 
Thanks

Comment: Identity is something unique for entity. You really have many entities with same id?

Comment: Yes many entities have same id.

Comment: And EF doesn't complain when you save them?

Comment: You're using DBSet as a method when it is a class. Call one of DBSet's methods instead.

Comment: id is actually loc_id i made the correction.

Comment: How is `DbSet` defined?

Comment: protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

Comment: Properties cannot be called like methods with parameters.

Comment: does every type of T have a loc_id?

Comment: Not all but the ones I will call will have it

Answer (score 0):

Your `T` type should be inherited from some other type which has `LocId` property. Example:

```
public class DatabaseEntity {
   // This is the type all your specific database entity types
   // should be inherited from
   public int LocId {get; set;}
}
```

Then you implement your generic repository method:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll(int loc_id) where T: DatabaseEntity
{
    return DbSet<T>().Where(item => item.LocId == loc_id);
}
```

Comment: OP is storing their DBSet in a property using protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }, so need to change that to return DbSet.Where instead of DBSet<T>().Where

Comment: @NickUdell: In the datacontext `Set<T>` can be used to identify the correct table by only using the type of the entity (generic `T` in this case). I think the answer was alluding to this feature, but wrongly used the classname `DbSet` instead.

Comment: I updated the code with. It will make sense of my issue. Thanks

Comment: @Flater in the comments on the question, OP stated they defined DBSet as protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }, unless I've made a mistake.

Comment: @NickUdell: True, but what I meant is that I think Dmytro was referencing the usage of `myContext.Set<T>()` to be able to retrieve the correct table from the context by passing only its entity's type. The generic method `Set<T>()` is both similar in signature, and it would be functionally correct here, so I assumed that to be the case.

Comment: @Flater Ah I see, good point. That would be two reasons it's wrong then!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to edit the lambda in the `Where` clause depending on your entity's loc_id property name, but this should work. It uses LINQ to query your DBSet for any entity where entity.loc_id equals the loc_id passed to `GetById`

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetById(int loc_id)
{
    return DbSet.Where(x=>x.loc_id == loc_id).AsQueryable();
}
```